# Routing Bug in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.5

I am creating a web app in **Laravel 5.5**, I have created authentication scaffolding via the **php artisan make:auth** command. The problem is that when I click on a button on my webpage to direct to ligin page I get error **Object Not found** . Seems to be an issue in my routing..

**Routes file**

```
Route::view('/', 'front.index');

Auth::routes();
Route::get('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');
```

Button am clicking

```
<li><a href="{{url('/login')}}">LOGIN</a></li>
```

**php artisan route:list**

```
+--------+----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                    | Name             | Action                                                                 | Middleware   |
+--------+----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /                      |                  | \Illuminate\Routing\ViewController                                     | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | admin                  |                  | App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@index                             | web,admin    |
|        | GET|HEAD | admin/addProduct       |                  | App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@addProduct                        | web,admin    |
|        | GET|HEAD | admin/profile          | profile          | App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@profile                           | web,admin    |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user               |                  | Closure                                                                | api,auth:api |
|        | GET|HEAD | dashboard              |                  | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                              | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD | home                   | home             | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                              | web,auth     |
|        | POST     | login                  |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                        | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD | login                  | login            | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD | logout                 |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                       | web          |
|        | POST     | logout                 | logout           | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                       | web          |
|        | POST     | password/email         | password.email   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail  | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset         | password.request | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm | web,guest    |
|        | POST     | password/reset         |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset/{token} | password.reset   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm        | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD | register               | register         | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm      | web,guest    |
|        | POST     | register               |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register                  | web,guest    |
+--------+----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<li><a href="{{route('login')}}">LOGIN</a></li>
```

and run

```
php artisan route:clear;
composer dumpautoload;
```

Read [Simple and Easy Laravel Login Authentication](https://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-and-easy-laravel-login-authentication)

Comment: Thanks for help but it still fails